# installing latest tcl/tk version

Tags: tcl

I am trying to install tcl/tk 8.5.11 on MacOSX. However, it is not being recognized; the old version 8.5.7 is showing up.
I have a separate folder on my desktop I am unzipping the files into.

I follow the instructions on the Tcl site (to the best of my ability).

I do:
"`% info patchlevel`"
and it gives:
"`8.5.7`"

which is what I don't want. The reason I want this new version is that I need it to be unthreaded. Whatever is currently there is threaded.
Can anyone offer ideas on how I get the new version to be recognized?

Comment: 8.5.7 is probably the system version on Snow Leopard. Your problem is probably that your PATH isn't set up correctly. How do you start the Tcl where you enter the 'info patchlevel'?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to put /usr/local/bin/ ahead of /usr/bin/ in your PATH.

I have installed ActiveTcl v 8.5.11.x in Snow Leopard.  For example, I can invoke this version directly:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/tclsh
% info patchlevel
8.5.11
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the first version of tclsh on the PATH is the old one. To force the use of the new one, you should either change your PATH environment variable *or* give the full path to the executable on the command line. With OSX, the easiest way to do that is to open a Terminal and drag the version of the tclsh executable that you want to use from where it is in Finder onto the terminal window (which pastes the path in directly).

However, you should be aware that in the future all versions of Tcl are likely to use threads more extensively (so as to enable better utilization of modern multi-core hardware). As a longer-term strategy, it might be best to investigate (and fix) the problems that are causing you to need an unthreaded build. (It's reasonable to use code that won't actually work in multiple threads; Tcl won't ever spring them on your code by surprise. But anything that won't work in a threaded build at all — even if only ever touched from a single thread — is a problem.)

Comment: i appreciate your response @Donal Fellows. I will try that. Just one more stupid question...where exactly is the Tcl executable? Tcl came with a bunch of folders when I downloaded it and I'm not sure which file is the executable.

Comment: @BeauGeste: Now _that_ I can't tell you; it's not in a standard spot or you'd be finding it already. Given that it's several days since you downloaded it, you should be able to use `locate tclsh` in a terminal to identify candidates. (That “several days” is because the database it uses is rebuilt about once a day.) You _could_ also try Finder/Spotlight, but I find that less useful for this kind of search.

Comment: Thanks @Donal Fellows. making progress...I can get the correct version now with info after your suggestions. I'm not trying to run a program and this is the warning its giving me: `Tk version mismatch: /usr/local/lib/tkConfig.sh from 8.5 Running Tk 8.5.11`

Comment: @BeauGeste: I'm not sure that that's a big problem. There were some changes in 8.5 to make it much fussier about version matching, but if it's all working _once built_ there's no big deal.